# DDMS: Screen capture: screen not available

Tags: android, screen, ddms

Android tablet 4.1.2 is connected via USB.
DDMS 24.0.2 (Win 7)

Device can be seen in the left pane, there is also log in the bottom pane. However, instead of the screen capture I see white rectangular with blue diagonal cross.
I assume I have installed drivers properly as well as turned on developer mode.

What can be the reason of the screen capture unavailability?

Comment: If this is an off-brand tablet, or especially if screen capture works for you on other Android devices, then the most likely possibility may be that the capability is simply not functionally implemented on your device.  The underlying details of how this is done vary between hardware and Android versions, and it is not functionality which gets much use, so it's easy to imagine it being overlooked by some outfit trying to get an Android port just functional enough to ship on the kind of cut-rate hardware that has been flooding the tablet market in recent years.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I can see my screen in Remote debugging  with Chrome. It is a bit pale, but it is visible.
That's why I've supposed that I might see screen in DDMS also.

Comment: I suspect that is done at the level of Chrome itself rather than through the Android display system, so all it does is indicate that there is basic connectivity to the device.  But if you are debugging the display of web content, perhaps it will work for your purposes.  Don't discount a well-aimed webcam either.